# exclude img opacity

Tags: css

I am trying this code:

```
<div id ="crop_image">
    <img class="one" src="http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/uploads/monthly_05_2010/post-380028-12747928967239.jpg.pagespeed.ce.yRppR_j7ae.jpg" />

</div>

#crop_image:not(.one) {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20); /* internet explorer */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.2;      /* khtml, old safari */
    -moz-opacity: 0.2;       /* mozilla, netscape */
    opacity: 0.2;           /* fx, safari, opera */
}
```

However, the img still have opacity. What is wrong ?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/djdhT/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing a few tricks (`inline-block`, `absolute` positioning, etc.) you can get a semi-transparent div to overlay an image.

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/djdhT/5/)

Comment: the red div should have some opacity.

Comment: I stand corrected... It's never that simple.  What exactly do you want?

Comment: I don't know if is possible. Different opacity for each element (div and img)

Comment: When you set the opacity of the container, it affects everything inside.  It would be like setting `display: none` on a container... things inside it shouldn't show up (like closing a box).  Do you want the image overlaid with a red rectangle that's partially transparent?

Comment: yes, is exactly what I want. But the img should be inside of div. however, this can be done with background and png...I think so.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6074/discussion-between-fakerainbrigand-and-loops)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this...(revised)

```
#crop_image img:not(.one)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, but I can explain why it is setting the opactiy to `.2`.

`#crop_image:not(.one)` means an element with the ID of `crop_image` which does not have the class of `one`.  If you look at your `crop_image` it does not itself have the class of `one` so this will match.  The `crop_image` contains an element which has the class of `.one`, but that is not what `not` does.

Comment: What i want is remove the opacity of the image, but set #crop_image with some opacity. Basically exclude the image or set opacity: 1. Do you understand what i mean ?

Comment: So you want the div to have opactiy .2 but the image to be 1?  Don't think you can do that, you'll need to remove the image from the div.